# Remove wp-mediaelement.css from wp_head

Tags: php, functions, video-player

I´m customizing the new core audio/video player via CSS in my *styles.css*. I tried to remove the *wp-mediaelement.css* with the following code in functions.php, because I don´t need it anymore.

```
function custom_deregister_styles()
{
  wp_deregister_style( 'mediaelement');
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'custom_deregister_styles', 100 );
```

The problem is, that this function removes the call of *mediaelementplayer.min.css* and *wp-mediaelement.css*. The following doesn´t work, too.

```
function custom_deregister_styles()
    {
      wp_deregister_style( 'wp-mediaelement');
    }
    add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'custom_deregister_styles', 100 );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move those declarations out of the action. Simply paste both of them in the functions.php file and it will work (tested).

```
wp_deregister_script('wp-mediaelement');
wp_deregister_style('wp-mediaelement');
```